# make Glide work as singleton for all classes

Tags: android, android-glide

I am working on module where it is responsible for handling `Glide` image loading

All other classes has to use `GlideFeatureModule` to load images

**GlideFeatureModule**

```
interface IGlideLoad{
    fun load(file: Any):GlideLoadImp
    fun context(context: Fragment):GlideLoadImp
    fun context(context: AppCompatActivity):GlideLoadImp
    fun context(context: Context):GlideLoadImp
    fun placeHolder(drawable: Drawable):GlideLoadImp
    fun placeHolder(drawable: Int):GlideLoadImp
    fun apply(requestOptions: BaseRequestOptions<*>):GlideLoadImp
    fun into(imageView: ImageView):GlideLoadImp
    fun build():GlideLoadImp
}
```

**classes using GlideFeatureModule**

```
glideLoad
         .context(context)
         .load(url)
          .into(profileImage);
```

Now I am stucked in how to use callbacks that `Glide` provides

```
.listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(...) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(...) {

                        }
                    })
```

I wanted to use it somewhat like

```
glideLoad.listener(new GlideLoadImp.GlideStatus() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailed() {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: You can create **extension function** for that, if you don't know then i'll provide.

Comment: please provide me ... that will be very helpful

Comment: Can you explain in detail what do you want to achieve from such function?

Comment: just wanted to hide loader and make imageview visible in onSuccess()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create your custom callback to get response from `RequestListener` interface.

So how you can get callback? You can simply pass **object** of such **interface** as method parameter so that callback can be handled.

Look example below :

```
/**
 * Method that loads image explicitly to view passed as parameter provided by string url to be load into.
 * It receives callback as method parameter to handle result.
 * @param view as {@link ImageView} object
 * @param url as {@link String} parameter
 * @param listener as {@link RequestListener} object
 */
public void loadImage(@NonNull ImageView view, String url, RequestListener<Drawable> listener) {
    Glide.with(view.getContext())
            .load(url)
            .listener(listener)
            .into(view);
}
```

& How one can use it

```
loadImage(imageView, "myUrl", new RequestListener<Drawable>() { //Here we will get callback
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@android.support.annotation.Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

> **Edit for O.P.:**

You can give this a try, Let's say you've class that being used as mediator right now as below :

```
class GlideLoad{
    //we store our listener object here to provide callback
    var callback : GlideLoadImp.GlideStatus? = null

    fun listener(listener: GlideLoadImp.GlideStatus?) {
        this.callback = listener
    }
}
```

and we set it from outside with method as from O.P.,

```
glideLoad.listener(object: GlideLoadImp.GlideStatus() {

        override fun onSuccess() {

        }

        override fun onFailed() {

        }
})
```

Now during our `RequestListener` callback, we can provide values or invoke our **callback listener** as below :

```
class GlideLoad {
... Some code
// some method having our RequestListener implementation
    object: RequestListener<Drawable>() {

        override fun Boolean onLoadFailed(...) {
            callback?.onFailed(you can pass params here if needed)
        }

        override fun Boolean onResourceReady(...) {
            callback?.onSuccess(you can pass params here if needed)
        }
    }
... Some other code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort . This will make my code directly depended on Glide library , which I don't want . I need to make Glide separately so that I can change it to any other library later

Comment: In such case, you want to implement your callback interface right?

Comment: yes ... This is what I am looking for . I achieved it ,but the RequestOption in glide can't take null object , so trying to make an extension function :)